# how to open camera in onPostExecute method of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to open the camera in `AsyncTask`, but after when the `doInBackground` hook method.
actually I am retrieving the data from the network(servlet), and if the retrieved data, matches the condition, I had set a variable say `int x=1 ; if (x==1) { camera.open() ;}`

please suggest me, what to do?

I had written some code

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class StartAtBootServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Start periodic service.
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        Intent srvIntent = new Intent(context, StartAtBootService.class); // NoLopper

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, srvIntent, 0);
        // Use context argument to access service
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Repeat every 5 seconds
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                10000,
                pIntent
        );
    }
}
```

**this is services**

```
public class StartAtBootService extends Service {
    public static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:1010/junction/AsynLocInsertionServ";

    String imei = "1234";
    String returnString = null;
    Integer returnedValue = 0;

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("StartServiceAtBoot1", "StartAtBootService Created1");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("StartServiceAtBoot2", "StartAtBootService -- onStartCommand()");

        new GetXMLTask().execute(url); // calls the AsyncTask

        return START_STICKY;
        // return START_REDELIVER_INTENT ;
    }

    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String output = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                try {
                    String Imei = "10101";
                    String Latitude = "333.33";
                    String Longitude = "44.44";

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1imei",
                            Imei));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2lati",
                            Latitude));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param3longi",
                            Longitude));

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    // String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, res);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                }// end of inner try block
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } // end of outer try block
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            return output;
        } // end of getOutputFromUrl method

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
            super.onPostExecute(output);

            Log.d("done LAtlong stored in mysql_onPost method",
                    " " + output.toString());
            if (output == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                getApplicationContext().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        } // onpost
    } // end of GetXMLTask
}
```

Comment: Could you please post some more code.

Comment: i had not code yet .. any suggestions  sir ? how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

set the result data type to int
and return 1 (if match) at end of doInBackground()

at onPostexecute(int result), the 1 will be passed, and there its safe to start camera.

Answer (score 0):

let say you get value from server and it is in `x` then do

```
onPostExecute(void result) {

if(x==1) {
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 
}

}
```

And add Uses Permission in your manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

for more, [read here](http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/)

Comment: it works fine ,, but i have AsynTask which start on BOOT_COMPLETE ..

i have error ::The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type my_StartAtBootService.myTask

my_StartAtBootService is service which starts on BOOT_COMPLETE with fixed Alarm time ,,, and myTask is the class where i had my AsynTask placed.

i just created the object of mytask in OnStartCommand() hook method of service ...
hope u get me..thx

Comment: if you have a context there then simply do context.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  else pass context in asyntask constructor

Answer (score 0):

we can write this code on `onPostexecute()`

```
// global declaration
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);   
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```